# The method of having 2 models in 1 view, is it possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to put 2 models in one view? My page is working fine with one model, however when i attempt to add the other model line below my code decides to start having a number of errors:

```
@model ProjectShop.Models.Delivery
```

My code that works before i add the line above is shown below:

```
@model ProjectShop.Models.Products

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Products";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ProductLayout.cshtml";
 }

<p>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.productname) </p>
```

What would be the method of having 2 models in one view enabling me to call data from two sources?

Edit:

This is a new class which will act as the view model for html page but i assume its not right at all:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using ProjectShop.Models;

namespace ProjectShop.ViewModels
{
public class ProductDelivTimes
{


        public Models.Products;
        public Models.Delivery;

}
}
```

Edit:

```
public class ProductDelivTimes
{


    public Models.Products ProductModel;
    public Models.Delivery DeliveryModel;

}
```

In my html file:

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectShop.ViewModels.ProductDelivTimes>
```

Edit:

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectShop.ViewModels.PerformanceTimes>
@{

Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
var grid = new WebGrid(Model, rowsPerPage: 5, defaultSort: "Name");

ViewBag.Created = TempData["ProductCreated"];
ViewBag.Created = TempData["ProductDeleted"];
}

@grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "grid",
    headerStyle: "gridhead",
    rowStyle: "gridRow",
    alternatingRowStyle: "gridRow",
    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    columns: grid.Columns(

grid.Column("Image", format: @<text><img src="@item.image"  alt=""   width="84px" height="128px"/></text>, style: "Image"),


grid.Column("Products", format: @<text>@Html.Raw(item.Products.name.Substring(0, item.Products.name.IndexOf(".") + 1))</text>, style: "Products")


                    ))
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have multiple Domain entities as a part of a view, consider creating a View Model that combines two data source models

Something like (just pseudocode):

```
ProductDeliveryViewModel
{
   // ProductModel
   // DeliveryModel
}
```

So you would have

```
@model ProjectShop.Models.ProductDeliveryViewModel

@Html.DisplayFor (model=> model.ProductModel.Property)
@Html.DisplayFor (model=> model.DeliveryModel.Property)
```

Comment: Thank you. Im trying to create my view model however i get syntax errors when attempting to enter both my models into the class: Models.Products; and Model.Delivery; please could you advise? Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand, can you update your question with your ViewModel

Comment: Your need to declare it with the type and the name, so it would be public Models.Products ProductModel; public Models.Delivery DeliveryModel;

Comment: Thank you, the viewmodel now seems to work and i have changed the model line at the top of my html page (see original post). Howevr i now get the following error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[ProjectShop.Models.Products]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ProjectShop.ViewModels.Delivery]'. Is this because my web grid is pointing to the incorrect place? (please also see original post).

Comment: Did you change the model on the top of the View-> i.e. @model ProjectShop.Models.Delivery

Comment: yeah i changed it to the following: (at sign)model IEnumerable<ProjectShop.ViewModels.ProductDelivTimes>

Comment: Post your entire code where you are binding your model to the grid

Comment: Have you tried var grid = new WebGrid(Model.DeliveryModel, rowsPerPage: 5, defaultSort: "Name")

Comment: Using that causes it to have a syntax error on DeliveryModel  saying "I am missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Answer (score 2):

Maybe write a wrapper model that contains the two data source models and decides which one to get the data from, when needed?

Comment: The data will always be needed, the other model required will be showing the delivery dates of each product on the page.

Comment: Yes, so just combine them into one "wrapper" model that knows how to combine the data from the two different models to serve to the display

Answer (score 2):

The teams I've been on would use a ViewModel class to wrap both business objects into one object that can be used by the view.  It can be as simple as having a property for each object.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I have acheived this by using a third 'container' model.

```
public class MainModel 
{

  public ProductModel productModel {get;set;}
  public DeliveryModel deliveryModel {get;set;}

}
```